# Spring OAuth2: XML -> Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-security-oauth2

i am just migrating a spring 3 application from xml-configuration to java config.

We are using spring 3.2.8 + spring security 3.2.4.
I am wondering how to move the following XML config to java.

```
<oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems (if you are not using spring boot) right now there is no direct possibility of doing a full java-configuration for SSO/OAuth2.

I got around it by using @import to load my old XML-based configuration-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ImportResource({"classpath*:spring-security-RSA.xml"})
public class SecurityRSAStrategyConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the opposite problem, I have a spring (not boot) application and need to authenticate to an external oauth2 IDP (in this case Azure AD), just using spring-security 3.2.1, spring fwork 4.3.18. Finding directions without spring boot is a challenge!